# Using Kal with tab view application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, calendar, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use Kal for my tab view application. It has already got 3 tabs, News, Calendar and About us. I'm fairly new to Objective-C aswell.

I think I have integrated Kal properly, it doesn't throw any errors when importing it.

How would I actually go about adding it to my SecondViewController though? From what I've understood, the example provided in the documentation just shows the calendar immediately on startup, which is not what I want. I have also checked out the Holiday example app, which also shows the calendar immediately.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply add it in the viewdidload of your secondViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    KalViewController *calendar = [[[KalViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:calendar.view];
    [self addChildViewController:calendar];
}
```

You also need to make sure that you include the calendar viewcontroller as a child viewcontroller to ensure that the viewcontroller hierarchy is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you mean that I should add the secondViewController as a child viewcontroller? I am on xcode 4.1.

Comment: Yes, there are two distinct hierarchies, the view hierarchy, and the viewcontroller hierarchy. Both must be maintained properly for the rotation events to propagate properly (and many other aspects).